# AngularJS Datatables sort on checked items

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, sorting, datatable

I am using anguarljs Lin Datatables [Lin Datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/)

The datatables work nice and search,sort works great, but there is a requirement to sort the datatable's on checked items. 
For example , when user checks the checkbox and wants to sort on basis of checked items the sorting functionality doesn't work.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest how to sort using Lin datatables on basis of check-boxes.

The html code for checking the check-box state is

```
    <td><input id="{{content.fileName}}" type="checkbox"
value="{{content.fileName}}" ng-model="content.isChecked"
ng-click="toggleSelection(content)" /></td>
```

Comment: I don't know the plugin, but it seems that it orders the tables based on the textcontent of the td-element, though the textcontent of your td-element with checkbox is always an emtpy string. I'm afraid that you have to add text to the td-element, like so `<span style="display:none">{{content.isChecked}}</span>`.   
Let me know if this works.

Comment: @sniels Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @sniels , Thanks i will make it, will let you know once done

Comment: @sniels As davidkonrad mentioned please see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kXFzUmcjikUOQliqn02Z?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the small [**`dom-checkbox`**](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/custom-data-source/dom-checkbox) plugin. It works with angular dataTables as well :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col ) {
  return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
    return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
  })
}
```

Then set the `#` column to use `dom-checkbox` as `orderDataType` :

```js
DTColumnBuilder
  .newColumn(1)  
  .withTitle('#')
  .withOption('orderDataType', 'dom-checkbox'),
```

have replicated your scenario here -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/kXFzUmcjikUOQliqn02Z?p=preview**